# $expand fetching all data without limit

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, odata, olingo

I have a problem with function "$expand". I have two entity A and B, which B is attributes of A(one-to-many). Problem is that the hibernate is fetching all data and it takes much time, in both entities I put pagination. I tried to use fetch type, mapped and join column but it does not help.
Here the hibernate request.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "attributes", fetch = FetchType.private 
List<TenderLotAttribute> tenderLotAttributes=new ArrayList<>();

Hibernate:
select
count(distinct cashlot0_.cash_lot_id) as col_0_0_
from
cash.cash_lots cashlot0_
Hibernate:
select
cashlot0_.cash_lot_id as col_0_0_,
cashlot0_.cash_id as col_0_1_
from
cash.cash_lots cashlot0_ limit ?
Hibernate:
select
distinct cashlota1_.lot_attribute_value as col_0_0_,
cashlota1_.cash_lot_id as col_1_0_,
cashlota1_.lot_attribute_name as col_2_0_
from
cash.cash_lots cashlot0_
inner join
odata.lot_attributes_exp cashlota1_
on cashlot0_.cash_lot_id=cashlota1_.cash_lot_id
order by
cashlota1_.cash_lot_id asc
```

How can I optimize the hibernate request? Pls, help.

Comment: Can you please post the URL and the version of Olingo you are using?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/SAP/olingo-jpa-processor-v4) the latest